# What is Better SQL Server Configuration?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, raid

First think : MDF and LDF separate on raid 1
Second think : All in one raid5.

Comment: ou don't need a seperate raid for the LDF, if your database is rarely updated. All other suggestions would depend on your data and usage, but you don't provide any informations.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your question a bit?  One can guess what you want to ask here, but I'm sure you'd get better answers to a better question.  A bit of information about your disk array would be useful for sure.  Knowing the typical load of it is often handy.

Comment: read/write ratio? Size of data/RAM ratio? OLTP, DW or BI workload type? Frequency and size of writes? Any secondary log reading workload (replication, DBM)?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what it is be used for really. For lots of writes I would look at raid 1 or 10 not raid 5 which would be used for lots reads (reporting). Unless you have a relatively new SAN then 5 would be ok due to better caching.

A different Physical disc for data and log files if you can. ALWAYS keep backups on a different disk to the data files this should be RAID 5.

As much Ram as you can get.